# Iterate over every option

Tags: c

lets say I have this array

```
int array[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

And I want to perform a certain function on every possible variation of this array (lets say each variable in the array has a minimum value of 0x00 and maximum value of 0xA).

```
int array[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
*Some Loop*
{
     someFunction(array);
}
```

In other words, I want to do *someFunction* on every permutation possible (from {0x00, 0x00, 0x00} to {0xA, 0xA, 0xA}), but I'm having trouble doing so, so I'm asking for help.

I hope I explained properly, thanks in advance!

Comment: C++ and C are different languages, and the answers will be very different in this case.  Please use just one tag.

Comment: Are you writing C code, or C++? They are not the same language, and you should not cross-tag automatically.

Comment: [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787854/1072468)'s answer below is perfectly good C or C++ code for this, so don't get so hung up on that, mkay?

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Except you wouldn't actually write it that way (hard coding the boundaries) and the "proper" way would differ between the two languages.

Comment: @SchighSchagh While that answer is great (I gave it an up-vote), you could get answers in C or C++ that does not work in the other. And really, shouldn't a beginner know what language they are working with?

Comment: BTW, since you need 1 loop per element of the array (per Oliver's answer), this won't work if your input is dynamic and the size is not known at compile time.

Comment: @user3311508, if you feel one of the two answers solved your problem pleas mark it so it does no show up in the unanswered category.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i=0x00;i<=0xA;++i){
   for(int j=0x00;j<=0xA;++j){
       for(int k=0x00;k<=0xA;++k){
          someFunction(i,j,k);
       }           
   }
}
```

Comment: I would change the loop bounds to `0x0A` to match OP's boundary condition, but otherwise this would work great.

Comment: Edited the loop to be `<=` since 0x0A is a valid array member.

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution would be something like

```
someRecursiveFunction( int *arr, int curbyte, int min, int max)
{
 int n;
 if( curbyte == 0 ) someFunction( arr );
 else for( n = min; n <= max; n++ ) {
  arr[curbyte-1] = n;
  someRecursiveFunction( arr, curbyte-1, min, max );
 }
}
```

and then in your main:

```
someRecursiveFunction( array, 3, 0, 0xA );
```